# Sending object C from class A to class B

Tags: python, design-patterns, class-design

I can't figure out how to design classes in my system.

In classA I create object selenium (it simulates user actions at website).

In this ClassA I create another objects like SearchScreen, Payment_Screen and Summary_Screen.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import selenium
import unittest, time, re

class OurSiteTestCases(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.verificationErrors = []

        self.selenium = selenium("localhost", 5555, "*chrome", "http://www.someaddress.com/")
        time.sleep(5)
        self.selenium.start()        

    def test_buy_coffee(self):

        sel = self.selenium

        sel.open('/')
        sel.window_maximize()

        search_screen=SearchScreen(self.selenium)
        search_screen.choose('lavazza')

        payment_screen=PaymentScreen(self.selenium)
        payment_screen.fill_test_data()

        summary_screen=SummaryScreen(selenium)
        summary_screen.accept()


    def tearDown(self):
        self.selenium.stop()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

It's example SearchScreen module:

```
class SearchScreen:
    def __init__(self,selenium):
        self.selenium=selenium

    def search(self):
        self.selenium.click('css=button.search')
```

I want to know if there is anything ok with a design of those classes?

Comment: Why do you need classes for SearchScreen etc? What are you gaining by making them into separate classes?

Comment: I gave only pseudocode example of my testcase. I have a lot of testcase, so I create SearchScreen etc to not duplicate code

Comment: @user278618: See my update at the end of my answer, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is fine. You have a set of tool classes, each of which needs to know its target. Then you have a toolkit class that coordinates these tools on a particular target.

```
class AgreePrice:
    def __init__(self, connection): ...

class PlaceOrder:
    def __init__(self, connection): ...

class ConfirmAvailability:
    def __init__(self, connection): ...

class BookingService:
    def __init__(self, connection): ...

    def book(self): 
        for Command in (ConfirmAvailability, AgreePrice, PlaceOrder):
            command = Command(self.connection)
            command.run()
            assert command.success()
```

There's nothing at all wrong with those kinds of class structures, in fact they come up all the time, and are a reasonably good design when the individual 'tool' classes can't be placed conveniently in one function.

If ever you find yourself with a class that has tens of methods in it, of which many can be grouped according to specific tasks, this is a good refactor.

As a general rule you want to make sure that your 'tool' classes (`SearchScreen`, etc) are at a conceptually lower level than your controller (your test cases). Which they are for you.

At their simplest these tool classes are a form of the [Function Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object) design pattern. Although in your case, you are calling more than just one method on each object, so they are a little more sophisticated.

---

Or, in short. Your design is fine, and very common.

Answer (score 3):

If SearchScreen/PaymentScreen/SummaryScreen only performs test logic, it looks to me like you might as well just put that logic in utility methods of OurSiteTestCases.

Possible design for the test_buy_coffee method (depending on what you actually do in SearchScreen et al):

```
def test_buy_coffee(self):

    sel = self.selenium

    sel.open('/')
    sel.window_maximize()

    # Replace SearchScreen
    self.__choose_search()
    # Replace PaymentScreen
    self.__fill_payment_data()
    # Replace SummaryScreen
    self.__accept_summary()
```

**Edit:**
If you need to factor out the test logic in __choose_search, __fill_payment_data and __accept_summary, to share it between tests, you may write corresponding utility test functions in a common module/package. Or, you could write a test baseclass which contains the selenium object (self.selenium) and has the "protected" utility methods _choose_search, _fill_payment_data and _accept_summary. It all depends on what's practical in your case :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use Chain of Responsibility pattern:

Definition:
    Avoid coupling the sender of a request to its receiver by giving more than one object a chance to handle the request. Chain the receiving objects and pass the request along the chain until an object handles it.

The example is in c# the:

```
  Handler h1 = new ConcreteHandler1();

  Handler h2 = new ConcreteHandler2();

  Handler h3 = new ConcreteHandler3();

  h1.SetSuccessor(h2);

  h2.SetSuccessor(h3);



  // Generate and process request

  int[] requests = { 2, 5, 14, 22, 18, 3, 27, 20 };


  foreach (int request in requests)
  {
    h1.HandleRequest(request);
  }
```

Here is you can see the complete documentation: http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternChain.aspx#_self1